# Blaschke points

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, geodesics

A *Blaschke point* of a metric space is a point so that every geodesic (i.e. locally shortest path) starting at that point and of length less than the diameter of the metric space is the unique shortest path between any of its points. It is known that if a smooth Riemannian metric on a compact connected surface has all points Blaschke, it is the sphere or real projective plane, with the usual metric, up to constant rescaling. What is the smallest number $n$ so that any compact connected surface with smooth Riemannian metric with $n$ or more Blaschke points is isometric to the sphere or real projective plane, with the usual metric, up to constant rescaling? It seems like $n=3$ should suffice. Clearly $n=2$ won't, as surfaces of revolution have pairs of Blaschke points.